# Statistical physics in cosmolgy

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, statistical-mechanics, big-bang

In https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/Sept03/Trodden/Trodden4_2.html and also in Mo et al. (Galaxy Formation and Evolution) the number density, energy density and pressure of the different particle species are expressed as integrals of the distribtuion function $f(\overrightarrow{x}, \overrightarrow{p}, t)$ over momentum space. Specifically to compute the energy density $\rho$ they use
$$\rho(t)\propto \int E(p) f(p,t) p^2 \mathrm{d}p$$
and then they use the well known energy-momentum relation from special relativity:
$$E(p) = \sqrt{p^2+m^2}$$
How is this justified? To derive this relation one clearly needs a Minkowski metric. My first idea was, that the relation is true in the locally inertial frame of the actual particle but I think it does not make sense then to integrate over all those energies computed in different frames...
Can someone help me out here?